# How to make "onAuthStateChanged" wait to "currentUser.updateProfile" to finish?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have a problem registering users in my Vue app... When a user register, I want to fire `updateProfile` to add more user data, and after that, in the `onAuthStateChanged` in my main.js save all that user data in vuex to use across my app, but the `onAuthStateChanged` excutes before the `updateProfile`, so in vuex displayName and photoURL are undefined.

How can I make the `onAuthStateChanged` wait to `updateProfile` to finish?

I have this function in my Register.vue component:

```
register() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(user => {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser.updateProfile({
              displayName: this.displayName,
              photoURL: this.photoURL
            })
            .then(() => {
              db.collection("users")
                .doc(user.user.uid)
                .set({
                  email: this.email,
                  displayName: this.displayName,
                  realName: this.realName,
                  photoURL: this.photoURL
                })
                .then(() => {
                  console.log(user);
                  this.$router.replace("/");
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  this.errorMessage = err.message;
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              this.errorMessage = err.message;
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
            alert("The password is too weak.");
          } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
          }
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
```

And have this in my main.js:

```
let app = "";

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);
  if (!app) {
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried making the method async and putting await in front of the call?

Comment: Same result... Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is probably because you don't return the asynchronous functions from the `register` method.

You currently have this

```js
register() {
      firebase // undefined as you don't return anything
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(user => {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser.updateProfile({
              ....
            })
            .then(() => { // undefined as you don't return in the previous then block
              db.collection("users")
                .doc(user.user.uid)
                .set({
                  ......
                })
                .then(() => { // undefined because you don't return in the previous then block
                 ....
                })
                .catch(err => {
                 ...
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              ....
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          ....
        });
    }
  }
```

Do this

```js
import { EventBus } from './eventBus.js';

register() {
  EventBus.$emit('user-registration-causes-auth-change', true)  // set this to true when the registration starts so that when eventbus listens to it in main.js, it won't update user profile (alternatively, replace with let self = this)
// (if following alternative route, this.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = true;)
  return firebase
  .auth()
   ....
   .then(user => {
          return firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser....
            .then(() => {
              return db.collection("users")
                ....
                .set({
                  ......
                })
                .then(() => {
                  EventBus.$emit('user-registration-causes-auth-change', false) // set it to false after you have finised updating the user profile.  
                   // if following alternative route, self.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = false;
                })
       })
    })
}
```

#### eventBus.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue(); // initialise an event bus here and export it so that it could be used in other files
```

#### Main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { EventBus } from './eventBus.js';

let app
auth.onAuthStateChanged(async() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      data: {
       isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange: false; // initialise it to false so that when you load the page, it won't be hindered from dispatching "fetchUser" if there's a user.
      },
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
  
  EventBus.$on('user-registration-causes-auth-change', (payload) => {
    app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = payload;
  })

  await Vue.$nextTick() // wait for the DOM to update
  
  if (user && !app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange) { // put the conditional here
    store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);
  }
})

EventBus.$off('user-registration-causes-auth-change', (payload) => { // this could be extracted into a handler
  app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = payload;
})
```

This is rough code, but the goal is to convey the information. You can clean it up as you please.

Comment: I already know why I'm getting undefined and isn't because of that... Its because when the user is created, the `onAuthStateChanged` dispatch the user data before the `updateProfile` have the chance to update the `displayName` and `photoURL`.

Anyway, I tried what you suggested, same result.

Comment: Hi, the only thing I can think of is to have some sort of variable you can send to the main.js using an eventBus. And in your checks, you can look out for that variable before dispatching the user. I will update my answer for you to see.

Comment: I have updated my answer, @ObedMonsalve. I have a sneaky suspicion that since the `data` property is initialised in the vue instance, it is available throughout the application and is reactive. Instead of emitting using an eventBus to emit a variable which then causes the data property to change, I feel you could change the value of  `isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` directly in the component. Try replacing the EventBus emissions with `this.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = true | false`. It should work.

Comment: I tried both ways, with the original `isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` event and `this.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = true` but got this [error](https://i.imgur.com/cnKvWBX.png) on both.

Also tried to change the data of the main.js to a function like a component, same result.

Comment: Hi, @ObedMonsalve. Of course it throws an error. I have updated my answer. Apologies. The two instances of `this` in the `main.js` file have been changed to `app` and the position of the eventBus listener has been changed. If you want to change the value of `this.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` in the `register` method, you have to declare a variable `let self = this` before `EventBus.$emit.....` and then do `self.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange = false`. This is due to the context in the `.then` callback not belonging to the vue instance.

Comment: No errors now, your code executes perfectly, but the result is the same... Even with all that, the `store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);` fires before the `updateProfile`.
I double checked the mutations and events, and there's no problem with your code, aparently `onAuthStateChanged` excutes instantly no matter what you do to slow it down.

Comment: onAuthStateChanged will execute, but this check ` if (user && !app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange) { // put the conditional here
    store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);
  }` should stop it. Could you check that `app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` is changing. If possible, we may have to use [Vue.$nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to make sure there's a change before `app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` is checked

Comment: Alternatively, if all this fails, could you move the update profile bit to a new method? Does it have to be in the registration bit? I am new to fire-base and I think  `onAuthStateChanged` is triggered when the profile is updated.

Comment: I have updated the answer, @ObedMonsalve, with `Vue.$nextTick` in `main.js`. I also imported `Vue from vue'.I hope it works as at this point, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: `app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange` value is changing perfectly fine, I checked the events tab and the vuex tab and it works just fine, the problem lies on the conditional, because it is checking the `user` and you only obtain access to it thanks to the `onAuthStateChanged`, In short, the condition itself depends on the activation of the `onAuthStateChanged` to work properly.
And no, `onAuthStateChanged` don't fire when the profile is updated.
And `await Vue.$nextTick()` didn't work... vs code throwed me a syntax error because you can't use that keyword outside an async function.

Comment: There is an `async` keyword here, @ObedMonsalve `auth.onAuthStateChanged(async() => {`. You probably missed it. Did you also see the updated conditional? `if (user && !app.isRegistrationTriggeringAuthStateChange) {
    store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);
  }`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `async`... But now I got an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.$nextTick is not a function`.

Comment: I finally solved it... The solution was so simple that I feel stupid, I just take to make another dispatch after the `updateProfile`.
I didn't wanted to make the update in another function because it can lead to update errors on slow connections (like mine, **Venezuela triggered**), but with that extra dispatch, everything works as intended.

Comment: Thank you very much for the intensive course in remote functions, this is a immense help.

Comment: I am happy you got your answer, @ObedMonsalve. Please post your solution for the benefit of anyone who comes on this page.